# Generate node JS docs when hover on a method?

Tags: node.js, webstorm

Hi all I am a Java programmer and I have to work on code written in Node JS. I am using WebStorm for understanding the code. In Eclipse when we hover on any method we usually get a javadoc.

Is there any way to generate Node JS docs on hovering on a method in WebStorm.

Comment: Well -- `Navigate | Quick Documentation` is the way to see the docs in IDEA-based IDEs. You can 1) Make that popup sticky so it will update its content for the element under caret automatically 2) or try `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General --> Show quick documentation on mouse move` option

Comment: I have used Both the options but still I am not getting the documentation for most of the methods. Is there any file which I need to import so that I could get the Node JS documentation on hover.

Comment: I'm not really a JavaScript/NodeJS person so cannot really help in this "extra/proper documentation" regard unfortunately.

Comment: No issues. Thanks for helping.